# FPPopover controller does no show

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, fppopover

Following files added to my project

```
FPPopoverController.m and .h (the controller)
FPPopoverView.m and .h
FPTouchView.m and .h
ARCMacros.h
```

And following function calling after pressing `UIBarButtonItem`

```
-(IBAction)popover:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Method called");

    //the view controller you want to present as popover
    MenuViewController *controller = [[MenuViewController alloc] init]; 

    //our popover
    FPPopoverController *popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc] 
                                          initWithViewController:controller]; 

    //the popover will be presented from the okButton view 
    [popover presentPopoverFromView:[sender valueForKey:@"view"]]; 

    //no release (ARC enable)
    //[controller release];
}
```

Just after pressing UIBarButtonItem I have seen Log `Method called` but not showing `popover view`

Which was working before converting to ARC my project.

What is the problem going on

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = sender;
UIView *btnView = [item valueForKey:@"view"];
[popover presentPopoverFromView:btnView];
```